# Extracting data from non-python nested lists in python (maybe json data?)

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, tuples

I have a bunch of data that I am parsing, and I've managed to get all of it into a database but there is one last part that is tripping me up, getting the date into the db in a "nice" format. If I can figure out how to extract just the date string from the data then it shouldn't be hard to use dateparser, but this part is really getting to me and my brain just doesn't know where to go.

This is the format of the data. There may be other key value pairs.

```
[("[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Wednesday, 3 March 2021'}]",)]
```

and the only thing I've done that is remotely useful is figuring out that python will allow me to list the key value pairs

```
[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Wednesday, 3 March 2021'}]
```

using

```
data = [("[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Wednesday, 3 March 2021'}]",)]
for a in data:
    for b in a:
        print(b)
```

The format of the data is:

```
[("[{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}]", "[{'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}]", "[{'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}]")]
```

I could bruteforce it, although I know this is straightforward and I just can't figure it out. Any help with finding an elegant and correct solution appreciated.

---

Here's the code that does what I want, thanks to @Kraigolas

```
data = [("[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Wednesday, 3 March 2021'}]",)]
for a in data:
    data = [eval(element)[0] for element in a]
    if(data[0]['key'] == "Date"):
        print(data[0]['value'])
```

Comment: Does the data look like `[("[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Wednesday, 3 March 2021'}]",), ("[{'key': 'Date', 'value': 'Thursday, 4 March 2021'}]",), ...]`? It's unclear

Comment: @Kraigolas I have updated OP with clarification on data formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved over several steps.

To start the problem, let:

```
data =  [("[{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}]", "[{'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}]", "[{'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}]")]
```

### Addressing the Tuple

You have a whole tuple inside your list. Let's just grab the tuple and work with that instead.

```
data = data[0] 
# ("[{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}]", "[{'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'}]", "[{'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}]")
```

### Processing the Strings

Notice that the elements inside of your tuple look like this

```
element = "[{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}]"
```

That would be a dictionary inside of a list if it wasn't a string! Let's use the `eval` command to get it in that form:

```
element = eval(element)  
# [{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}]
```

### Getting rid of the outer list

To get rid of the list we grab the 0th element to get back just the dictionary

```
element = element[0] 
# {'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}
```

### Getting the data

Index for "value" to get back the date.

```
element = element["value"]
# "value1"
```

Putting this all together into a list comprehension

```
dates = [eval(element)[0]["value"] for element in data[0]]
# ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your initial reply with some slight modification to allow checking of each key value pair. You got me over the hurdle of getting through all those brackets!

Comment: @yuuuu Happy to help!